# Arabic tooltips issue in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, arabic, right-to-left

I have developed many bilingual(English and Arabic) sites, but recently I have observed tooltip issue in IE(<=8 versions) for Arabic version sites.

No 'RTL' applied for Arabic tooltips and there is no word formation of Arabic Characters.

All my sites are W3 Compliance.

I did not understand, is it a browser issue or do I need to fix in code to display proper tooltips in IE?

Answer (score 0):

you have to install RTL language support in the host system (e.g. WinXP) to show the RTL tooltip in correct order in IE7.

you can do that from Control Panel -> Regional and Langauge Options -> Languages

check the "Install files for complex scripts and right-to-left languages (including thai)" checkbox and click OK.

Comment: But how can we do for the production shared environment?