# Title on links doesn't show in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a link with a title attribute on a HTML page.
Since this page is in Arabic, I use dir="rtl".
As soon as I add some styling with margin in it, it stopes working on **IE7** (the tooltip doesn't show)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/V72Ba/1/) is an example

(This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201364/arabic-tooltips-issue-in-ie) didn't help)

Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use css property `display:block;`. I tried in IE9 as IE7 browser mode and it showed me title.

Comment: Thanks @daniyel, it works ! (BTW, inline-block also works if someone is interested)